# How to edit contents of iframe of external domain?

Tags: jquery, iframe, dns, external

I have done a lot of searching on this topic but still couldn't get it working. What I am trying to do is customizing the contents of a external domain `iframe` with jQuery. I need to execute a function on my page when a CSS property changes on the `iframe`.

So is there any way to achive this?

Comment: is the external page under your control?

Comment: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prohibits you from doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is a subject of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In other words you can't edit the contents of an external iframe.

Comment: No the page is not under my control.
Can i do it by grabbing the contents somehow to my page and then customize it ?

Comment: If you know the URL of it then using ajax GET you can get the contents of it. `$.get(url, function(data){ alert(data); });`

Comment: @papaiatis that won't work either as you cannot get the HTML of an external domain via an AJAX request, also due to the Same Origin Policy.